# How to store value in structure like in C in django Model

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

```
***class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    length = models.FloatField()
    width = models.FloatField()
    depth = models.FloatField()
    color_text = models.TextField()
    color_rgb = models.ForeignKey(ColorRGB, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    color_cmyk = models.ForeignKey(ColorCMYK, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    treatment_text = models.TextField()
    treatment_number = models.FloatField()
    transparency_text = models.TextField()
    transparency_number = models.FloatField()
    total_carat_weight = models.FloatField()
    country_of_origin = models.TextField()
    hardness_text = models.TextField()
    hardness_number = models.FloatField()
    pieces_text = models.TextField(
    pieces_number = models.IntegerField()
    price_pkr = models.FloatField()***
```

please see the color_rgb field and color_cmyk field. One has 3 integer values to be stored and the other has 4 integer values to be stored.

I am trying to define this as below. Question is that is this the correct way or there is better way to do it ?

---

```
class ColorRGB(models.Model):
    R = models.IntegerField()
    G = models.IntegerField()
    B = models.IntegerField()
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing it the other way - having the `ColorRGB` model refer to `Product` with the foreign key:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # All the other product fields as normal, except the color ones


class ColorRGB(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='color_rgb',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    R = models.IntegerField()
    G = models.IntegerField()
    B = models.IntegerField()


class ColorCMYK(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='color_cmyk',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    C = models.IntegerField()
    M = models.IntegerField()
    Y = models.IntegerField()
    K = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can refer to the colours in the same way, with e.g. `Product.color_rgb` etc. You can also define sub-models of the sub-models, if you like.